# Regular expression that matches the first string after a marker

Tags: c#, regex

Given a string like this, I would like to create a Regular Expression that captures the string "Identificador". This string is localized, thus the problem.

As a hint, I have thought that it may be retrieved easily, because it's the string just after the "------------". Each entry is separated by this "-------" and the first element is the string I want. So the Regex could return "Identificador" or an array of { "Identificador", "Identificador", "Identificador", ... } (one string for each entry).

Here is the sample input:

```
Administrador de arranque de firmware
-----------------------------------
Identificador           {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}

Administrador de arranque de Windows
----------------------------------
Identificador           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \efi\boot\bootarm.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
booterrorux             Simple
default                 {default}
displayorder            {838bb5a3-712f-11e8-b4ea-001a7dda710e}
                        {default}
                        {7619dcc9-fafe-11d9-b411-000476eba25f}
bootsequence            {01de5a27-8705-40db-bad6-96fa5187d4a6}
timeout                 30
displaybootmenu         Yes
processcustomactionsfirstYes
persistbootsequence     Yes

Cargador de arranque de Windows
-----------------------------
Identificador           {311b88b5-9b30-491d-bad9-167ca3e2d417}
device                  ramdisk=[F:]\PROGRAMS\UpdateOS\UpdateOS.wim,{ramdiskoptions}
path                    \windows\system32\boot\winload.efi
description             Windows Update OS (Boot from WIM)
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                ramdisk=[F:]\PROGRAMS\UpdateOS\UpdateOS.wim,{ramdiskoptions}
systemroot              \windows
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

Cargador de arranque de Windows
-----------------------------
Identificador           {7619dcc9-fafe-11d9-b411-000476eba25f}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \windows\system32\boot\winload.efi
description             Windows Phone
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
bootdebug               No
nointegritychecks       Yes
osdevice                partition=F:
systemroot              \windows
bootmenupolicy          Standard
bootstatuspolicy        IgnoreAllFailures
ems                     No

Aplicaci¢n de arranque de Windows (1020000a)
------------------------------------------
Identificador           {01de5a27-8705-40db-bad6-96fa5187d4a6}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \windows\system32\boot\mobilestartup.efi
description             Mobile Startup App
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {311b88b5-9b30-491d-bad9-167ca3e2d417}
recoveryenabled         Yes
nointegritychecks       Yes

Aplicaci¢n de arranque de Windows (1020000a)
------------------------------------------
Identificador           {0ff5f24a-3785-4aeb-b8fe-4226215b88c4}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \windows\system32\boot\ffuloader.efi
description             FFU Loader (User Invoked)
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
custom:26000201         Yes

Aplicaci¢n de arranque de Windows (1020000a)
------------------------------------------
Identificador           {default}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \EFI\boot\BootShim.efi
description             BootShim
nointegritychecks       Yes
testsigning             Yes

Aplicaci¢n de arranque de Windows (1020000a)
------------------------------------------
Identificador           {838bb5a3-712f-11e8-b4ea-001a7dda710e}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \Windows\System32\BOOT\developermenu.efi
description             Developer Menu

Aplicaci¢n de arranque de Windows (1020000a)
------------------------------------------
Identificador           {bd8951c4-eabd-4c6f-aafb-4ddb4eb0469b}
device                  partition=G:
path                    \windows\system32\boot\resetphone.efi
description             Reset My Phone Application
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
custom:26000206         Yes

Configuraci¢n de EMS
--------------------
Identificador           {emssettings}
bootems                 No

Configuraci¢n del depurador
---------------------------
Identificador           {dbgsettings}
description             Windows Debugger Settings

Configuraci¢n global
--------------------
Identificador           {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
bootuxtransitiontime    5000
booterrorux             Simple
extendedinput           Yes
nobootuxtext            Yes
nobootuxprogress        Yes
nobootuxfade            No
nokeyboard              Yes
mobilegraphics          Yes
custom:250000e0         1
chargethreshold         255
custom:25000511         90
bootflow                0x0
offmodecharging         No

Configuraci¢n del cargador de arranque
------------------------------------
Identificador           {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
advancedoptions         No
optionsedit             No

Opciones del disco RAM de configuraci¢n
-------------------------------------
Identificador           {ramdiskoptions}
description             Ramdisk Options
ramdisksdidevice        partition=G:
ramdisksdipath          \boot\boot.sdi
```

Comment: Are these multiline strings? Or all in a single line? Does it have to be a single regular expression?

Comment: Can you give more information how the result should look?

Comment: The result should be "Identificador". I need to know which words comes after ----------- It'll be the same in each entry. I will extend the listing in the OP.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand expected result, but for example `Identificador\s+\{(.+)\}`. Does it solve your task and why if not?
It will return list Identificadors like
`Identificador           {fwbootmgr}`
`Identificador           {bootmgr}`
...

Comment: I don't know this format but a parser shouldn't be hard to build for it. If it is not a homemade format, a parser may already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is as simple as using a lookbehind for the "-" and a whitespace.

```
(?<=-\s)(\w*)
```

Live regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/nULXkE/1/).
This assumes there are no other trailing hyphens elsewhere.

For .NET use:

```
 (?<=-\s+)(\w*)
```

Comment: I'm trying it in .NET (C#) and it doesn't capture the strings like in the Live regex site :(

Comment: @SuperJMN try `(?<=-\s+)(\w*)`. You can test [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Comment: That WORKS! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=` asserting what is on the left side are one or more hyphens `-+` followed by one or more whitespace characters `\s+` and then match one or more times not a whitespace character `\S+`

[`(?<=-+\s+)\S+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d-%2b%5cs%2b%29%5cS%2b&i=Administrador+de+arranque+de+firmware%0d%0a-----------------------------------%0d%0aIdentificador+++++++++++%7bfwbootmgr%7d%0d%0adisplayorder++++++++++++%7bbootmgr%7d%0d%0a%0d%0aAdministrador+de+arranque+de+Windows%0d%0a----------------------------------%0d%0aIdentificador+++++++++++%7bbootmgr%7d%0d%0adevice++++++++++++++++++partition%3dG%3a%0d%0a)

[Lookbehind demo](http://rextester.com/ISFJ73933)

Or or match from the start of the line `^` one or more hyphens `-+` followed by one or more whitespace characters `\s+` and capture in a group (your value is in group 1) one or more times  not a whitespace `\S+`.

[`^-+\s+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KbCwuI/1)

[Group demo](http://rextester.com/SWRYF57437)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
---\n(.+?)\s{2,}
```

https://regex101.com/r/RD5kOe/1

Comment: Why three hyphens? "---" the ruler is made of hyphens, but not exactly 3 :)

Comment: It doesn't matter it this case. Better than check for all hyphens, or explicitely write it. Three are enough...